# Entity Framework Select Navigation ICollection As IQueryable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have just started using EF Code First to implement a simple blog.

I have a Post object which has a product variable

```
virtual Product Product { get; set; }
```

The Product class has a collection of categories

```
virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

Finally the category has a collection Posts.

```
virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

This so far has worked well. Now I want to get posts for a particular category. I was originally doing this in my PostRepository by passing in a category Id : such as

```
public IQueryable<Post> GetPosts(int catId) {
    var q = _db.Posts.Select(p => p).Distinct();
    if (catId > 0)
        q = q.Where(p => p.Product.Categories.Any(c => c.ID == catId));
}
```

This works great, however I also use a CategoryRepository to get my category. Since the category has a list of products, which in turn has a list of posts, I thought it would be better to just use that, and remove the category from my PostRepository.

However, I have run into an issue. To get the posts, I use this in my controller:

```
model.Category = _cr.GetCategory(catId);
model.Posts =
    new PaginatedList<Post>(model.Category.Products.Select(p => p.Posts)
               .AsQueryable(), pageNumber, _defaultPageSize);
```

The PaginatedList is the one from NerdDinner taking in an IQueryable. Now, this errors because I am passing in a

```
IQueryable<ICollection<Post>>
```

So my question is how can I get a IQueryable from my Category entity? I'm sure the answer is simple, but I've been trying all kinds of combinations to no avail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you try `.SelectMany(p => p.Posts).AsQueryable()`?

Comment: No I hadn't but I have now! Thanks Ladislav. I didn't even know about SelectMany but after reading about it now, it's obvious that was what I needed. Thanks again!

Comment: I was having same situation, Thanks!